# Defining Bit Vectors in Z3 using fixed characters

Tags: python, z3, z3py

Can we define our input BitVec() in Z3 in such a way that we know part of the input and the other part we want Z3 to solve?

As an example, in the code below, I am defining a Bit Vector to represent a string of 10 characters.

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

input = [BitVec("input%s" % i, 8) for i in range(10)]

s.add(gen(input) == 0xAABBCCDD)
```

In the above example, gen() is a function which generates a DWORD using the input.

Now, let's say, I already know the first few characters of the input. For example, the input is always in the format: CHECKXXXXX

where, X are the unknown characters.

How can I define the input in Z3 now to take advantage of the known characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Since you are generating a symbolic input for each character of your input, simply add the corresponding assertion for the elements that you know:

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

input = [BitVec("input%s" % i, 8) for i in range(10)]

known = "CHECK"
s.add([input[i] == ord(known[i]) for i in range(len(known))])

print s.check()
print s.model()
```

This prints:

```
sat
[input4 = 75,
 input3 = 67,
 input2 = 69,
 input1 = 72,
 input0 = 67]
```

which is precisely what you wanted. Now you can call your `gen` function and further constrain the other parts of `input` to get a full model.

Alternatively, you can use the `BitVecVal` function to directly create constant bit-vectors, and not bother creating the symbolic variants in the first place: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a74d306d60d4cc4432907f58306b41686 But I think going with pure symbolic inputs and adding constraints is nicer, because it simplifies programming. The minuscule performance savings of having not created symbolic variables in the first place would be hardly worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your response :)